# sum with conditional if

Tags: php, sql

I have data as below:

[image]

Here is the query:

```
SELECT   a.product_id,coa_id, product_group_id, amount
FROM t_monthly_data a, p_product b, p_report_set c
WHERE a.product_id = b.product_id
      AND a.coa_id in (51110001,51110005,51110007,51110011) 
      AND CATEGORY = 'DIRECT COST'
      AND period = 201701
GROUP BY a.product_id,coa_id, product_group_id,amount
```

How do I sum the amount which have the same product id but different coa id?

My expectation :

```
| PRODUCT_ID |           COA_ID            | PRODUCT_GROUP_ID | AMOUNT

|     AV     |  51110001,51110005,51110007 |        SIO       | 550400555
|     DA     |           511100011         |        PSC       | 327500
```

Can i get the value like result above?

Comment: have you put SUM() at the amount?

Comment: I did before, but I got the wrong result from my expectation. So I remove the SUM() from my query. if I sum the amount above manually (using calculator) I got my expectation

Comment: I say stick with the calculator -- who needs these stinking computers anyway?

Comment: I've already updated my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to sum by product id then you need to group by product id.  This will give you one row for each product id with the sum of the amounts.  (I also put count in there for you.)

```
SELECT   a.product_id, sum(amount) as sum_amount, count(*) as count_items
FROM t_monthly_data a
JOIN p_product b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE a.coa_id in (51110001,51110005,51110007,51110011) 
     AND CATEGORY = 'DIRECT COST'
     and period = 201701
GROUP BY a.product_id
```

Comment: I've already used this query, but I need coa_id for becoming a key in my report. could you update your answer, sir?

Comment: @rigen, um, no.   I don't understand your requirement.   Please update your question to include the expected output.  As stated I don't know what you want.

Comment: this problem already solved sir. I've improved my query using your query as my reference. Thank you so much :)))

Comment: @rigen which platform are you using for SQL, mySQL, DB2, Oracle, SQL Server.  The solution depends on this.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10g for my platform, sir

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COA_ID, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM table GROUP BY COA_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a SQL statement. Try

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT), COA_ID  FROM tablename GROUP BY COA_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT
    ProductID,
    SUM(IF(PaymentMethod = 'Cash', Amount, 0)) AS 'Cash',
    -- snip
    SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM
    Payments
WHERE
    SaleDate = '2012-02-10'
GROUP BY
    ProductID
```